# Creating a KML Heatmap in C# application

Tags: c#, .net, kml, heatmap, geotiff

I have a bunch of geodetic data that I want to create a heatmap for to display in Google Earth. Two options I see are to create custom heat blob Polygons in Google Earth. This has an advantage of easily aligning perflect on the earth, but I'd potentially have thousands of polygons over a large area, so there'd be a lot of latency in the system.

Another option would be to create an image file (like PNG), and overlay it on to Google Earth as a ground image overlay. This works in theory, but I'm not getting my image to line up properly on the earth since I'm taking lat/long data, applying it to a 2D image, and then overlaying the 2D image on tot he globe. The blobs are close, but they're off.

Is there another option that I'm overlooking? I thought maybe GeoTIFF was the right format here, but I'm having trouble finding something in .NET that can generate a GeoTiff. Is there another approach I've overlooked?

Comment: @bleakgadfly why did you remove my heatmap tag? The question is about heatmaps.

Comment: My mistake, was supposed to replace the Google Maps-tag (see [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9191137)) so you'd get more exposure from the .NET-tag but seem to have replaced the wrong tag. Apologies!